# Google Maps - Array of Locations from SOQL List

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

How could I populate a javascript array like below, from a SOQL Query?

```
var DemoLocationData = [
                    [49.2812668, -123.1035942, "26 E Hastings St, Vancouver" ], 
                    [49.2814064, -123.1025187, "71 E Hastings St, Vancouver" ], 
                    [49.2812336, -123.1020622, "122 E Hastings St, Vancouver" ], 
                    [49.2813564, -123.1012253, "138 E Hastings St, Vancouver" ], 
                    [49.2811625, -123.0985032, "242 E Hastings St, Vancouver" ]
                ];
```

This is so I can display my all of custom object's types location on a Google Map (e.g Cars).
I have already achieved this for a single Car, and I am displaying this inline on the master detail page - but now I am developing a standalone page.

Comment: Do you mean SOQL query?  If so, I suggest editing the question.  Stack Exchange won't let others do short edits.

Comment: @JagularI have edited the post - did not realise I have made the typo - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around my original problem using a remote action.
This gets the information I required using a query, and then returns a list of Tree__c objects.
I then iterate over this list and add them to the map as markers.

**VisualForce Page**

Additional Code added to JavaScript, this calls the remote action, and populates the DemoLocationData list with the results

```
function getData(){
      TreeMapMainController.getTreeCoordinates(function(result,event){
        DemoLocationData = result;
        initialize()
    });
```

I also had to modify the creation of the markers loop

```
     for (var i=0, l=DemoLocationData.length; i<l; i++     )
            {
                // the for..in statement should be use with caution, and its not intented to be used with an array. You should a for loop instead! 

                var p = DemoLocationData[i];
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.Geo_Location__Latitude__s, p.Geo_Location__Longitude__s);
                bounds.extend(latlng);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: p.Name
                });
}
```

**Apex Controller Code**

```
public with sharing class TreeMapMainController {


       private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
 @RemoteAction
 public static list<Tree__c> getTreeCoordinates()
 {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Geo_Location__Latitude__s, Geo_Location__Longitude__s, Height__c FROM Tree__c];
 }

  public TreeMapMainController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;

  }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want a string to hold the resulting output:

```
public String locations { get; set; }
```

Inside the function where you want to populate the data, you can just do the following:

```
List<List<Object>> output = new List<List<Object>>();
for(Location__c record: [SELECT Lat__c, Long__c, Street__c, City__c FROM Location__c]) {
    output.add(new List<Object> { record.Lat__c, record.Long__c, record.Street__c+', '+record.City__c});
}
locations = JSON.serialize(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can build it as a variable in your controller.

```
String locationData = '[';
for (Location__c loc: [SELECT Lat__c, Long__c, St__c, City__c FROM Location__c])
{
  locationData += '[' + loc.Lat__c + ', ' + loc.Lon__c + ', "' + St__c + ', ' + City__c + '" ],';
}
locationData = locationData.substring(0, locationData.length() -1) + ']';
```

Page:

```
var demoLocationData = {!locationData};
```

You might need to tweak it a little but this should be pretty close to what you want.

Comment: -1 Think carefully before constructing JSON manually; you have an injection vulnerability in your code. Also, if no results are returned, your JSON will also be malformed, causing script errors. Even so, stripping the last comma isn't necessary in JavaScript anyways. It's much easier to give beginners a foolproof code design.